# Can't clone a field in Logstash and only lowercase one of them

Tags: ruby, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am using Logstash RSS Input to collect and tag Google News alerts. In order to tag properly, I want to normalize the text first and also maintain the original casing for display on the UI.

I have tried the following, but every combination seems to end up with BOTH the original and the clone field lowercase, without specifically asking Logstash.

Method one- use mutate { add_field

```
input {
 rss {  [my RSS feed URLs] } 
}

filter {
 mutate
    {
        add_field => ["displayTitle", "%{@title}"] }
 mutate
    {
        add_field => ["displayText", "%{@message}"] }
 mutate {
    lowercase => [ "title","message" ] }


if "3d-print" in [title] or "3d-print" in [message] { mutate { add_tag => "3d printing" } }

output {}
```

Method two- use Ruby code to clone event

```
input {
 rss {  [my RSS feed URLs] } 
}

filter {

 ruby {
       code => "event['displayTitle'] = event['title']" }
 ruby {
       code => "event['displayText'] = event['message']" }


 mutate {
    lowercase => [ "title","message" ] }

if "3d-print" in [title] or "3d-print" in [message] { mutate { add_tag => "3d printing" } }

output {}
```

Method three- use Clone plugin to clone event

```
input {
 rss {  [my RSS feed URLs] } 
}

filter {
clone {
    add_field => { "%{title}" => "displayTitle" } }

 mutate {
    lowercase => [ "title","message" ] }

if "3d-print" in [title] or "3d-print" in [message] { mutate { add_tag => "3d printing" } }

output {}
```

All three of these methods produce output with BOTH the 'displayTitle' and 'title' fields to be lowercased, even though I only used mutate { lowercase => on the title field.

The same is true for the 'displayText' and 'message' fields. I want the displayTitle and displayMessage fields to stay preserved with the original casing.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try doing the lowercase in a second filter{} block.

Comment: Thanks @AlainCollins! That did seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @alain-collins pointed out, you have to do the lowercase in a second block.

The reason for this is related to how logstash works.  It inherits methods like `add_field` from the `filter` class.  The add_field only gets called once all of the `mutate` filters are done.

So you need to do this:

```
mutate { 
  add_field => { 
    "displayTitle" => "%{title}",
    "displayMessage" => "%{message}"
  } 
}
mutate { lowercase => [ "title","message" ] }
```

Your ruby version of it would have worked if you added .clone on the end.  Without that it's making a shallow copy of the string, so that when you lowercase it, its the same string being modified.

Comment: Many, many thanks @Alcanzar. I appreciate the explanation of the underlying functionality. I tried Alain's suggestion and it worked AFTER I moved the add_field {} block to the very end, after the other filter blocks.